# Mice in R - how can I understand what this command does?

Tags: r, r-mice

```
mice_mod <-
  mice(titanicData[, !names(titanicData) %in%
                     c('PassengerId','Name','Ticket','Cabin','Survived')], 
       method='rf')
mice_output <- complete(mice_mod)
```

I am new to R and we had a college lecture yesterday. What does this command do? I have read the online documentation and broke down the command to a series of outputs, with no joy.

Comment: you mean the mice function itself?

Comment: please specify your question. The mice function does fill empty values by an algorithm. In this case it is using the random forest imputations "rf". For using the wanted columns he is using every name, which is not in the called names. The complete command, is using the mice object and creating a new dataframe with the filled values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mice function approximates missing values. In you case you are using the "rf" statement, which means the random forest imputations algorithm is used. Since I can't reproduce your dataset, I'm using `airquality` which is a built in dataset by R with `NA` values. Those can be approximated. You are creating kinda a prediction model with `mice`. Actually it is a `mids` object, which is used by mice for imputed datasets ([documentation](https://stefvanbuuren.name/mice/reference/mids-class.html)). If you want to use those imputations, you can call `complete` for creating the filled dataframe.

```
library(mice)
df<-airquality
mice_mod <- mice(df, method='rf')
mice_output <- complete(mice_mod)
```

When you compare `df` and `mice_output`, you'll see the `NA` values  in `Ozone` and `Solar` got replaced.

In your example your lecturer is using all names which are not in the called list of names. So he is filtering the dataframe beforehand.

---

If you want more information about the algorithm: regarding to the [documentation](https://stefvanbuuren.name/mice/reference/mice.impute.rf.html) it is described in

> Doove, L.L., van Buuren, S., Dusseldorp, E. (2014), Recursive
>   partitioning for missing data imputation in the presence of
>   interaction Effects. Computational Statistics \& Data Analysis, 72,
>   92-104.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is a great help! One final quesition - am I correct in saying that ('PassengerId','Name','Ticket','Cabin','Survived') - are just all being excluded because they have most likely no impact on the passenger age field (which is where the NA's are being replaced). Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @user3600952 I'm not quite sure, but normally the simple algorithms are build like, that they just use the columns separately. So my guess they exclude those columns because they are not needed and want to safe time or they use other preparations. Without context it's hard to tell. I guess it's just data preparation.